# Adding pages creates a gap under my first page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a page with a list and every item in the list is a link to other pages, if I add only one other page and link it with a list item, everything is but when I try and add another page and link it to the second item, it creates a gap under the list...

I tripple-checked and i can't find anything wrong with my code...
Am i missing something?

**PS: Also, after I click one of my items and it slides me to the other page and them I go back to #pageone, the gap is no longer there...everything is fine...**

**My HTML**

```
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone" data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h1>handbook</h1>
        <form class="ui-filterable">
        <input id="myFilter" data-type="search">
        </form>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-inset="true">
                <li data-icon="action">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="thumbs/jquery.png">
                        <h2>title</h2>
                        <p>text</p>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#firstpage" data-transition="slide" data-></a>
                </li>
                <li data-icon="action">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="thumbs/jquery.png">
                        <h2>title</h2>
                        <p>text</p>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#secondpage" data-transition="slide" data-></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--page-->
<div data-role="page" id="firstpage" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h1>handbook</h1>
        <div class="article">
            <h2 class="align_center">Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p class="align_center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam varius tristique velit eu pretium. Morbi ac consequat justo. Nunc cursus massa ut risus sodales, vitae ultrices sem scelerisque. Vivamus vel massa sit amet lacus dapibus sollicitudin. Aenean gravida, mi ut faucibus viverra, arcu dui mattis risus, vitae aliquet nunc neque sed sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#pageone"  class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/page-->
<!--page-->
<div data-role="page" id="secondpage" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h1>handbook</h1>
        <div class="article">
            <h2 class="align_center">Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p class="align_center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam varius tristique velit eu pretium. Morbi ac consequat justo. Nunc cursus massa ut risus sodales, vitae ultrices sem scelerisque. Vivamus vel massa sit amet lacus dapibus sollicitudin. Aenean gravida, mi ut faucibus viverra, arcu dui mattis risus, vitae aliquet nunc neque sed sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#pageone"  class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/page-->
```

The CSS is the basic jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.css plus the following for the article:

```
.article{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: do you have css to go with that?

Comment: @g_m well, I updated the CSS but it's the basic jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.css plus one extra style for the article div that I added in my question now..

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem. Can you put it in a jsfiddle? <jsfiddle.net>

Comment: @g_m I am trying to do that just now

Comment: @g_m I am not able to reproduce it into a jsfiddle, it's not the same, no matter how many pages I add...and I have added all my styles and libraries into that jsfiddle and it;s not the same...could it be the plugin that prevents the screen from rotating? It was the only one I couldn't add into the jsfiddle...

Comment: Hmm well I cant see whats happening with the code here, so my advice is to inspect the elements and see where the gap is coming from. Good luck!

Comment: @g_m Well, I am creating a new project and isolating the code to see where it's coming from, no luck whatsoever...

Comment: @g_m I found the 'bug'...it's a very stupid one too...check my answer to my own question..

Comment: ok thats quite random. good find!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for those of you experiencing the same issue, I have found the problem, it's one I never thought could be the cause, I changed only one thing in the jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.css.

I added shorter transition times for faster animations and that's what f***ed up my app...it should remain like this:

```
.in {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration:350ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    -moz-animation-duration:350ms;
    animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    animation-duration:350ms
}
.out {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration:225ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    -moz-animation-duration:225ms;
    animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    animation-duration:225ms
}
```

### I really can't understand why this was affecting my page...please, if anyone knows the theory behind this weird 'bug', leave a comment or a link.